# Rxjava2 distinctUntilChanged() not working properly after first time

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

I am trying to use `.distinctUntilChanged()` and its not passing value to `switchmap()` after first time.

```
RxTextView.textChanges(etUserQuery).debounce(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).filter(charSequence -> {
        if (charSequence.toString().isEmpty()) {
            etUserQuery.setHint("Please type username");
                return false;
            } else
                return true;
        }).distinctUntilChanged()
        .switchMap(charSequence -> vm.dataFromNetwork(charSequence.toString()))
        .subscribe(fetchUserResponce -> {
            noDataText.setVisibility(fetchUserResponce.getItems().size() == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            mUsersListAdapter.updateData(fetchUserResponce.getItems());
        }));
```

Is it correct place to use `.distinctUntilChanged()`?

Comment: The `CharSequence` the textChanges gives you is mutable and should be turned into `String` before it is passed along.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've just added  `.map(CharSequence::toString)` and I think its working.

Comment: So `distinctUntillChanged()` only works for immutable emits? Can you please explain. @akarnokd

Comment: `textChanges` gives you the same `CharSequence` reference and `distinctUntilChange` relying on `Object.equals()` will find it equal to itself all the time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the comments:

The `CharSequence` the `textChanges` gives you is mutable and should be turned into `String` before it is passed along.

`textChanges` gives you the same `CharSequence` reference and `distinctUntilChange` relying on `Object.equals()` will find it equal to itself all the time.